# How to scroll an AccessibilityNodeInfo view with precise scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility

I want to scroll an accessibility node info which is a ScrollView widget.
I can only perform these two scrolls

```
parentNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARD)
parentNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD)
```

is there a way to give position to AccessibilityNodeInfo to which it can scroll?